# Show dates saved in CoreData by year sections

Tags: date, core-data, swiftui, sections

I'm working on a simple app that should add dates based on a certain range.
At the moment it should only add the current date to CoreData and sorts them into sections by year.

The below code works but it shows every year as often as there are dates. I know it is because of the 2 ForEach-loops. Does anyone know how to show every section (year) only once. Below the code and the result when adding 2 dates.

```
struct ScheduleView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Schedule.date, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
    private var dates: FetchedResults<Schedule>

    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(dates, id: \.id) { date in
                Section(header: Text(String((Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: date.date!)).year!))) {
                    ForEach(dates, id: \.id) { date in
                        HStack {
                            VStack {
                                Text("\((Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date.date!)).day!)")
                                Text("\(months[(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: date.date!)).month! - 1])")
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                            }
                            .padding(5)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Schedule")
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
            Button(action: { addDate() }, label: {
                Label("Add Dates", systemImage: "calendar.badge.plus")
            })
        }
    }

    private func addDate() {
        withAnimation {
            let newDate = Schedule(context: viewContext)
            newDate.id = UUID()
            newDate.date = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Example with 2 dates added with the add date button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxkia.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close... I had to change `Schedule` to the `Item` since you didn't provide info on your object but everything else should work.

```
struct YearSort: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    //Matched Fetch to generic Item since details about Entity were not provided
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
    private var dates: FetchedResults<Item>
    
    let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
    var years: [Int]{
        var result = [Int]()
        for date in dates{
            let year = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: date.timestamp!).year!
            if !result.contains(year){
                result.append(year)
            }
        }
        return result
    }
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(years, id: \.self) { year in
                Section(header: Text(year.description)) {
                    ForEach(dates.filter({date in
                         Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year], from: date.timestamp!).year! == year
                    }), id: \.id) { date in
                        HStack {
                            VStack {
                                Text("\((Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date.timestamp!)).day!)")
                                Text("\(months[(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: date.timestamp!)).month! - 1])")
                                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                            }
                            .padding(5)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Schedule")
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
                Button(action: { addDate() }, label: {
                    Label("Add Dates", systemImage: "calendar.badge.plus")
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private func addDate() {
        withAnimation {
            let newDate = Item(context: viewContext)
            //newDate.id = UUID()
            //Provides a random yeah +/- 3 years
            newDate.timestamp = Date().addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(-60*60*24*366*Int.random(in: -3...3)))
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```